# How can I do an average after a GroupBy in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ query and I am trying to get the average value of ActualSize for each day. Here is what I have tried but I am having a problem with this line:

```
ActualSize = g.ActualSize.Average()
```

Can anyone tell me how I can get the average as g.Average is not an option here:

```
var Disp  = Start
            .Select(x => new StartDisplay
            {
                DateYYMMDD = x.DateYYMMDD,
                ActualSize = (x.ActualHeight * x.ActualWidth) / 1000
            })
            .GroupBy(x => x.DateYYMMDD)
            .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
            .Select(g => new StartDisplay
            {
                DateYYMMDD = $"20{g.Key.Substring(0, 2)}/{g.Key.Substring(2, 2)}/{g.Key.Substring(4, 2)}",
                ActualSize = g.ActualSize.Average()
            })
            .ToList());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass an expression to `Average()` specifying the property to use.  Try this:

```
ActualSize = g.Average(s => s.ActualSize)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.GroupBy()` yields an [`IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2), which derives from `IEnumerable<TElement>`.

Thus, you can call the `Average()` function directly on the values in `g`:

```cs
ActualSize = g.Average(x => x.ActualSize)
```